# Style in Kivy python3

Tags: python, kivy

Как в python 3 kivy делать стили например как в css и тд... 
Скиньте сайт или документацию в каком месте искать 
Мне например нужно чтобы в блоке был box-shadow или же border-radius

Comment: Гугление выдало: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54559271 + https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/8g2zdm/does_kivy_support_html_css_and_javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы будете удивлены, но в Kivy уже реализованы стили. Вам нужно стилизовать, например, метку. Создаете файл `styles.kv`, и стилизуете:

```
<StyletLabel@MDLabel>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    theme_text_color: "Custom"
    font_style: "Caption"
    shorten: True
```

Загружаете этот файл в первую очередь и дальше в своем коде просто используете `StyletLabel`, где все параметры, кроме текста, уже указаны. Все очень просто.